What is the approximate ingredient cost per coffee for a local coffee shop in NYC?
I know it depends on many factors, such as the type of coffee, ingredients, and suppliers, but I'm hoping for any realistic example. This could be a calculation based on your knowledge of the industry or your own experience running a coffee shop in NY (e.g., for a cold brew of size X that I sold for Y, it costs me Z).
